# Slicing operation causing buffer overrun and leaking user passwords?

Tags: security, go, buffer-overrun

I have a server that has a function to return the registration date of a user. Any user can see any non-hidden user (in this example only user2 is hidden). The server gets a `dateRequest` from a client and uses `id` from that to find the corresponding user's date in the user file:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
)

const datelen = 10

//format: `name 0xfe date age 0xfd password`; each user is seperated by 0xff
var userfile = []byte("admin\xfe2014-01-0140\xfdadminpassword\xffuser1\xfe2014-03-0423\xfduser1password\xffuser2\xfe2014-09-2736\xfduser2password")

func main() {
    c := clientInfo{0, 0, 0}
    fmt.Println(string(getDate(dateRequest{c, user{0, "admin"}})))
    fmt.Println(string(getDate(dateRequest{c, user{0, "admin______________"}})))
    fmt.Println(string(getDate(dateRequest{c, user{1, "user1"}})))
    //fmt.Println(string(getDate(dateRequest{c,user{2,"user2"}}))) // panic
    fmt.Println(string(getDate(dateRequest{c, user{1, "user1_________________________________________________"}})))
}

func getDate(r dateRequest) []byte {
    if r.id == 2 {
        panic("hidden user")
    }
    user := bytes.Split(userfile, []byte{0xff})[r.id]
    publicSection := bytes.Split(user, []byte{0xfd})[0]
    return publicSection[len(r.username)+1 : len(r.username)+1+datelen]
}

type dateRequest struct {
    clientInfo
    user
}
type clientInfo struct {
    reqTime uint64
    ip      uint32
    ver     uint32
}
type user struct {
    id       int
    username string
}
```

```
$ go run a.go 
2014-01-01
dminpasswo
2014-03-04
r2password
```

As you can see, it works correctly to receive the dates of the users, but if the request has extra bytes on the username, part of the user's password gets returned instead. Not only that, but if you keep adding more bytes, it returns data from user2, which is supposed to be hidden. Why?

When executing `main`'s third line of code, `user` and `publicSection` in `getData` are "admin�2014-01-0140�adminpassword" and "admin�2014-01-0140". But then it returns "dminpasswo". How is slicing `publicSection` ("admin�2014-01-0140") returning "dminpasswo"? It looks like a buffer overrun problem, but that shouldn't happen because Go is memory-safe. I even tried reading past the buffer of `publicSection` by printing `publicSection[len(publicSection)]`, but it panics as expected.

I also tried replacing all the `[]byte` with `string`, and that fixes the issue for some reason.

Comment: You're not slicing outside the bounds of the slice, there is no out of bounds access. You're slicing based on the length of the supplied username, which isn't the same as what's in the userfile slice

Comment: Ah, I see your confusion now, you can slice past the len, up to cap.

Comment: As a matter of app design, I wouldn't let my app security depend on my handling of a custom format and arithmetic, even with the `cap` thing taken care of. I'd put a 'public' flag or a 'visibility' field in your user struct, store the password using a salted one-way function like `bcrypt`, and have some thing else handle the persistence, like a DB or `encoding/json`.

Answer (score 6):

Slice expressions check the bounds of the upper index against the slice capacity, not just the length of the slice. In effect, you can slice past the length of the slice. You cannot however slice outside the bounds of the underlying array to access uninitialized memory.

http://play.golang.org/p/oIxXLG-YEV

```
s := make([]int, 5, 10)
copy(s, []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5})

fmt.Printf("len:%d cap:%d\n", len(s), cap(s))
// > len:5 cap:10

fmt.Printf("raw slice: %+v\n", s)
// > raw slice: [1 2 3 4 5]


fmt.Printf("sliced past length: %+v\n", s[:10])
// > sliced past length: [1 2 3 4 5 0 0 0 0 0]

// panics
_ = s[:11]
// > panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range
```

If you really want to prevent slicing past the length of an array, in go1.3 or later you can set the capacity as the third argument when slicing.

```
// set the capacity to 5
s := s[:5:5]
// now this will panic
_ = s[:6]
```

Comment: If you are on the current Go, you can use the three-valued slice operation to reduce the `cap` as well, which really does stop access past the end: http://play.golang.org/p/rpiszxkFN-

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to say. It *is* strange that you can slice past the end of `s`. I didn't know you can do that. But here it appears to be initialized with zeros instead of some random memory.

Comment: @Dog: from the spec: `For slices, the upper index bound is the slice capacity cap(a) rather than the length.` In Go, all accessible memory is initialized. You can't access arbitrary memory without using `unsafe`.

Comment: @Dog: put another way, it's not random memory; it's memory you put particular data into to before the `publicSection := ...` line.

Comment: But why is slicing `publicSection` ("admin�2014-01-0140") returning "dminpasswo"? If the slice is out of bounds shouldn't it just return zeros like in your example?

Comment: @Dog: because you didn't copy the bytes to a new slice, you're just viewing part of the original array.